# What's the correct way to switch views (and/or controllers) in iOS5?

Tags: ipad, model-view-controller, ios5

I've read that I should be careful when loading/unloading views in an iPad/iPhone app, as doing it the wrong way will create problems with orientation-change detection and other event listeners.  There are so many opinions out there it's making my head spin!

Here are the specifics:

- I have 8 views in a storyboard
- The user experience is such that after the 1st view is done, I never need reference it again.  View 2 here ya go...
- I have no idea whether all 8 should be attached to a different controller (it seems the code would be cleaner, but I can give on that)
- I'm using an empty viewcontroller, as none of the standard navigationcontroller, etc. fits my needs here

Should I keep all the views in one controller and not worry about it?  Should I break it down into 8 controllers (if so, what's the appropriate way for the window to load/unload the controllers)?  What would you suggest?

Comment: Hi, landons. If you go to iTunes and search for Stanford Paul Hegarty (and select the FALL 2011), you'll get some video lectures that will guide you A LOT. For your question try watching video lecture 6, it's about Multiple MVC's and Segue's =) ps. please accept if someone's answers your question xD. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to develop an app that works a bit like a power point presentation.

When I had to develop such an app I picked the 1 view controller plus 8 views method.

**Each view** has a button that sends a notification to the view controller to load another view as soon as it was clicked.

**The view controller** contains a load method that listens to the notification. As soon as the notification arrives, the view controller removes the current visible view and loads the requested new view.

I don't know whether this way is the best, but it is fast to implement, easy to understand (at least in my opinion :-) ) and supports non linear view switching, though you don't need that. I also didn't encounter any problems with orientation changes.

If you are not sure whether this method is the right one for you, you can create a working prototype in about 15 minutes, just put a label and a button on each view and try it yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Yes, like a powerpoint with user input.  I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has some comments.  If not, I'll accept yours.  Thanks!